# Submitting a java FORM in R with RSelenium

Tags: java, r, forms, selenium

I am trying to use RSelenium to post a form here http://www.censusindia.gov.in/Census_Data_2001/Village_Directory/View_data/Village_Profile.aspx

I am able to collect all of the values from the dropdown menus, but I cannot figure out how to submit the form to retrieve the table data.

I have tried a number of commands

```
#Setting up the proxy server
RSelenium::checkForServer()

#Openning the Remote Driver
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000)
remDr$navigate("http://www.censusindia.gov.in/Census_Data_2001/Village_Directory/View_data/Village_Profile.aspx")

stateElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", "ctl00$Body_Content$drpState")
stateElem$setElementAttribute(value = "18") #for state "Assam"
```

and

```
remDr$executeScript("document.forms[0].submit();", list(value = "18"))
```

and variants of

```
document.forms["aspnetForm"].elements["stateElem"].value = "18"
```

I would like to be able to run this over a loop for district, subdistrict, and villages for select states.

I know I am not giving the community much to work with here, but I new to RSelenium and java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend and I were able to (painfully) figure out a solution to this problem using Python. I would still love to learn a way to do a similar task with R. Below is the code:

```
import mechanize 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "http://www.censusindia.gov.in/Census_Data_2001/Village_Directory/View_data/Village_Profile.aspx"

def select_element(br, form, value):
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br[form] = [value]
    return br.submit()

def get_page(state, district, sub_district, village): 
    """ Get village data """
    # I have no idea why exactly this works, the form uses javascript callbacks and
    # it seems that you need to submit the form for each selection or you get an error.
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(URL)
    # Could probably parse the responses at each stage to get valid entries for the next sub-unit.
    select_element(br, 'ctl00$Body_Content$drpState', state)
    # read html and pull out disticts
    select_element(br, 'ctl00$Body_Content$drpDistrict', district)
    select_element(br, 'ctl00$Body_Content$drpSubDistrict', sub_district)
    r2 = select_element(br, 'ctl00$Body_Content$drpVillage', village)
    return r2.read()

state = '35'
district = '01'
sub_district = '0004'
village = '00026500'
print(get_page(state, district, sub_district, village))

parameters = {'35': 
            {'01': 
            {'0004': ['00026500']}}}

foo = []        
for state, districts in parameters.items():
    for district, subdistricts in districts.items():
        for subdistrict, villages in subdistricts.items():
            for village in villages:
                foo.append(get_page(state, district, subdistrict, village))
                with open('foo', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(get_page(state, district, subdistrict, village))
```

I am very new to Python and prefer to use R for this task. Is this possible?